# Uploadify gives error HTTP Error (302) in yii

Tags: php, ajax, session, yii, uploadify

Yesterday I integrated [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) in a Yii application and it worked good. But suddenly I found that it does not work rather showing error `HTTP Error (302)`. I found this is happened only firefox, IE and Crome are okay.

In below of main.php file I wrote:

```
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'method'   : 'post',
        'auto'     :false,
        'multi'    : true,
        'formData'     : {
            'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
        },
        'swf'      : '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('cp/project/UploadImage')?>'

    });
});
```

and in controller:

```
public function actionUploadImage(){
    $directory = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/temp';
    if (!is_dir($directory)) {
        mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
    }

    $verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

    if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

        $filename  = basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
        $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newName       = md5(time()).'.'.$extension;

        $targetFile = $directory . '/' . $newName;

        $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

        if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile))
        {
            $model = new ImageTemp();
            $model->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
            $model->image_hash = $newName;
            $model->session_id = Yii::app()->session['imageUpload'];
            $model->save();
        }

    }
}
```

Everything was good but suddenly, I have been facing this error.

Comment: 302 is technically not an *error*, it's a *redirect*. Based on past experience, I am guessing Firefox is not passing session cookies in the Flash request, so Yii is telling it to authorize first. If that is indeed the case, you will need to implement something similar to http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/ .

Comment: Thanks, it helps me to fix the issue. I fixed now.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer so others with the same problem can benefit from finding this post.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue and left answer here how I have fixed if anybody got any help. As per reference of uploadify http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/ and http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/customizing-the-server-side-upload-script/ I wrote at the beginning of the controller :

```
function init(){

    if(isset($_POST['SESSION_ID'])){
        $session=Yii::app()->getSession();
        $session->close();
        $session->sessionID = $_POST['SESSION_ID'];
        $session->open();
    }
}
```

and initialized uploadify as:

```
$session_id = Yii::app()->session->sessionID;
$session_name = 'SESSION_ID';
$swf = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/uploadify.swf';
$uploadifyImg = Yii::app()->createUrl('cp/project/UploadImage');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('uploadify', "

$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'method'   : 'post',
        'auto'     :false,
        'multi'    : true,
        'formData' : {'$session_name' : '$session_id'},
        'swf'      : '$swf',
        'uploader' : '$uploadifyImg'

    });
  });
");
```

It would helpful who face such issue.